# How do I remove blank space in an Array from user input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

If I receive an input such as:

```
up 1, down 2, down 3, left 5
```

And I save this as an array, it will give me

```
["up 1", " down 2", " down 3", " left 5"]
```

But I need to delete the spaces before down and left!

Any ideas?

Comment: your output is invalid.

Comment: `gets.chomp.split(', ') #=> ["up 1", "down 2", "down 3", "left 5"]`

Comment: _"I save this as an array ..."_ – how do you convert the input to an array? Show your code, please.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 3):

Since you only want to remove the whitespace **before** certain strings use **[lstrip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-lstrip)**:

> Returns a copy of str with **leading** whitespace removed.

```
arr = ["up 1", " down 2", " down 3", " left 5"]
arr.map(&:lstrip)
# => ["up 1", "down 2", "down 3", "left 5"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`String#strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-strip):

```
array = ["up 1", " down 2", " down 3", " left 5"]
p array.map &:strip
# ["up 1", "down 2", "down 3", "left 5"]
```

`strip` returns a copy of str with leading and trailing whitespace removed, `lstrip` and `rstrip` do the same just respectively for left or right:

```
p '     ayayayayay     '.strip    # "ayayayayay"
p '     ayayayayay     '.lstrip   # "ayayayayay     "
p '     ayayayayay     '.rstrip   # "     ayayayayay"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought...

In the off case that you "receive an input" as a string such as:

```
str = "up 1, down 2, down 3, left 5"
```

You could do:

```
str.gsub(', ', ',').split(',')
```

Which gives:

```
 => ["up 1", "down 2", "down 3", "left 5"]
```

OR, if you're not a moron (like me), you could do:

```
str.split(', ')
```

As Sebastian (very politely) points out.

Answer (score 1):

How about using squish to remove whitespaces.

```
["up 1"," down 2", "down 3"," left 5"].map(&:squish)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to delete the spaces before down and left!

Answering the exact question stated:

```
["up 1"," down 2"," down 3"," left 5"].
  map { |e| e.gsub(/\s+(?=down|left)/, '') }
#⇒ ["up 1", "down 2", "down 3", "left 5"].
```